# Why is there a level of precedence for operators such as static_cast?

Tags: c++, operator-precedence

[According to cppreference.com, the C++ `static_cast` operator's level of precedence is 2](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Why are those levels even defined? I can't think of any reason. Can anyone provide an example?

Comment: If there was no precedence, your code would be indeterministic.

Comment: Is precedence level two by chance the same as the precedence for function application? And what's the source for this?

Comment: +1: It's a fair question, reasonably well stated.

Comment: RageD: I’m sorry for the misunderstanding, but I didn’t want to question the interest of precedence altogether. By "those levels", I meant "the levels of the C++ cast operators" :)

Comment: @victor: Use a `@` symbol so that RageD is notified about your reply. 8 months is long enough to know that! Click "help" next to the comment box for more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard doesn't define precedence levels; these can be *derived* from the grammar.

Like any other syntactical feature, `static_cast` has a place in this grammar. Because its use requires parentheses its operand expression can never be ambiguous, but that only means that it makes no sense to bother deriving a precedence level for it from the grammar, not that its place in the grammar itself is meaningless. Thus the standard is doing nothing crazy here.

What's pointless is that whatever source you cited listed a precedence level for `static_cast`. It's not *wrong*, it's just pointless.

Answer (score 3):

> The C++ cast operator’s level of precedence is 2

Who said this? The standard doesn't define operator precedence. It defines the grammar in a BNF-like notation.

Comment: @ChristianAmmer: `cppreference.com` is not the standard. So go and ask the one who wrote this page. I guess he did it this way because formally `static_cast` is a *postfix-expression*, along with `.`, `->`, `[]`, etc...